# Do iterations in Promise.each execute atomically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I'm using Bluebird promises.

Let's say I'm trying to copy an image to a given path, and then delete the original image. In other words, cut and paste. I'll be using Promise.each to do this for multiple images and multiple paths.

My question is: do each iteration in the Promise.each loop runs atomically?

Let's say I'm copying the first image to the first path. Copy is an async function. Is there a chance that the next iteration, for the next copy, will start before the first copy is finished?

Generally, is there a chance that NodeJS will fire the next iteration whilst waiting for the first I/O to finish?

Edit:

I'm posting a code sample. To make it more simple, I removed the "delete the image" part, and I'm just trying to copy a single image to multiple paths.

`Promise.each(somePathsArray[], function(path){
    return copy(simpleImage, path); // async function, returns a promise
}).then(function(){
    console.log('Done');
})`

Comment: Show us your code please.  It really depends upon exactly how your code is written inside the `Promise.each()` loop and whether you are properly chaining and returning a promise or not.  `Promise.each()` will await a promise you return from it and thus serialize the operations, but that will only work if all your operations inside the loop are chained to a promise that you return from within the loop.

Comment: And, "atomically" is probably the wrong word in your question since that generally means something different.  I assume you mean "serially".

Comment: No, I don't really mind if the execution order is serial. I'm interested to know if every action inside the iteration will be executed before the next one fires up.

Comment: @mpoureki: That's what "serial" means. It isn't what "atomic" means.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html):

> If the iterator function returns a promise or a thenable, then the result of the promise is awaited, before continuing with next iteration.

So your iterator function should return the promise from `copy` (or more likely from the `delete` that's chained to the `copy`). If you *don't* do that, then the next iteration won't wait for it. If you do, it will.

E.g., as near-pseudo-code:

```
Promise.each(theArray, entry => doCopy(entry).then(() => doDelete(entry)));
```

Or in ES5:

```
Promise.each(theArray, function(entry) {
    return doCopy(entry).then(function() {
        return doDelete(entry);
    });
});
```

Proof:

```js
var paths = ["one", "two", "three"];
function copy(path) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Resolving " + path + " promise");
      resolve(path + " done");
    }, 500);
  });
}
Promise.each(paths, function(path) {
  console.log("Processing: " + path);
  return copy(path);
}).then(function() {
  console.log("each is done");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.4.7/bluebird.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm doing. Actually, I removed the delete part, and I'm trying to copy the same image to different paths, but the next iteration seems to be fired before the previous copy is done.

Comment: @mpoureki: "seems to"? I'd prove that as a first step. Then I'd look at your `copy` function to see why it's resolving before the copy is complete. I don't think the Bluebird documentation is wrong.

Comment: @mpoureki: I've added an example using Bluebird demonstrating that the next iteration definitely does wait for the promise returned by the first one before continuing.

Comment: Sorry, bad choice of words. When I'm trying to copy the same image multiple times, I get this error. The next iteration is fired up whilst the image is still being copied. I used promisifyAll for the image handler module, which is a simple wrapper to the fs module.

Comment: @mpoureki: Whatever it is, it's in your `copy` function, not `Promise.each`, which behaves as described.

Comment: Honestly I'm not aware of the way that NodeJs handles I/O actions in terms of execution order, that's why I started this thread. I don't know if they're considered the same as a simple timeout. I've used Promise.each many times in the way you just described it. Also, thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @mpoureki: No worries. I think the question you actually asked (about `Promise.each`) has been answered. I think you may want to fiddle around with your `copy` function a bit more, and if you're still stuck, post a question with its contents, what you're seeing, and how you want it to behave instead. Good luck,

Comment: Will do. There must be something that I'm not aware of in it. Interestingly enough, in the same example, Promise.all executes just fine :) Have a nice day!